# return html for every key in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I do apologize in advance I'm a JS/ReactJS newbie and I have had trouble phrasing the question, so if this is already answered somewhere I am sorry.

I have an object like this:
`Object {Joy: 0.719115, Extraversion: 0.59527, Agreeableness: 0.650457}`

I'd like to be able to return html for all of the keys in the object. As of right now it only returns the html for the first key (obviously, as return breaks the loop, if I'm not mistaken). How do I achieve rendering of html of all the keys from the object?

```
import React from 'react'

export const MessageSentiment = (props) => {
  var sentiment = JSON.parse(props.sentiment)
  console.log(sentiment)
    for(var key in sentiment ) {
      console.log(key, sentiment[key])
      return (<h1>{key}: {sentiment[key]*100}</h1>)
    }
}
```

These are the output and required output

```
Output:
<h1>Joy: 71.9115</h1>


Expected output:
<h1>Joy: 71.9115</h1>
<h1>Extraversion: 59.527</h1>
<h1>Agreeableness: 65.0456</h1>
```

Not sure if this has anything to do with it, but I get a warning in the console:

```
../src/components/messages/MessageSentiment.js
  6:5  warning  The body of a for-in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype  guard-for-in

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)

printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:196
handleWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:209
connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:255
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js:49
(anonymous) @ main.js:274
SockJS._transportMessage @ main.js:272
EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:44
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ websocket.js:35
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things here.

1. You need to always return one single element, in this case a div. Inside of this element you can have whatever you want, but it has to be a single parent component.
2. You will use `map` to iterate an array and get a new array. In this case the new array will contain the `<h1/>` elements.

```

```
export const MessageSentiment = (props) => {
  const sentiments = JSON.parse(props.sentiment);
  const keys = Object.keys(sentiments);

  return (
    <div>
     { keys.map(key => (<h1 key={key}>{key}: {sentiments[key]*100}</h1>)) }
    </div>
  );    
}
```

```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

A React component can't return multiple React elements. You should wrap them inside `<div>` or any other container element.

```js
export const MessageSentiment = (props) => {
  var sentiment = JSON.parse(props.sentiment)
  return (
    <div>
      {
        Object.keys(sentiment).map(key => (
          <h1 key={key}>{key}: {sentiment[key]*100}</h1>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

And remember: [keys](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.

Comment: Both solutions are identical - I only marked the other solution as correct since it was the first one! But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need to collect all the HTML in the array  and return it. you can do 2 way

1. using map - map return new array without modifying existing array

.

```
export const MessageSentiment = (props) => {
              var sentiment = JSON.parse(props.sentiment)
              return (
                     <div>
                      {
                         Object.keys(sentiment).map((key, index) => <h1 key={index}> {key}:{sentiment[key]*100}</h1>)
                      }
                    </div>
                      )
              }
```

2. Using array push method

.

```
 export const MessageSentiment = (props) => {
     var sentiment = JSON.parse(props.sentiment)
     let itemList = [];
     for(var key in sentiment ) {
       itemList.push(<h1>{key}: {sentiment[key]*100}</h1>)
     }
     return (
             <div>{itemList}</div>
           )
     }
```