# Return HTML tag in array of object map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects mapping to return as a component but some of the content has an HTML tag. How can I return it rendering the HTML tag inside it?

```
const listContent = [
  {
    title: 'Sample Title 1',
    content: 'Sample of only text here'
  },
  {
    title: 'Sample Title 2',
    content: 'Sample of only text here with <span>Should render as span</span>'
  },
];


{listItemContent.map(item => (
  <ListItem>
    <h1>{item.title}</h1>
    <p>{item.content}</p>
  </ListItem>
))}
```

Comment: @jabaa Yes. ReactJS

Comment: Hi, you might want to have a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597329/return-html-for-every-key-in-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [React fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), like so:

```js
const listContent = [
  {
    title: 'Sample Title 1',
    content: 'Sample of only text here'
  },
  {
    title: 'Sample Title 2',
    content: <>
      Sample of only text here with <span>Should render as span</span>
    </>
  },
];
...
{listItemContent.map(item => (
  <ListItem key={item.key}>
    <h1>{item.title}</h1>
    <p>{item.content}</p>
  </ListItem>
))}
```

Note that you should ideally also add a `key` to each React element of an array.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use react's [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```
{listItemContent.map(item => (
   <ListItem key={item.key}>
   <h1>{item.title}</h1>
   <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: item.content}} />
   </ListItem>
))}
```